# What to pay attention when installing SSIS in a cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, clustering, installation

I'm improving my previous questions with more info here.

we have a 2 node cluster environment and one of them died. we created a  new node to replace it and added to the cluster ( no sql or ssis yet ).

I noticed that against microsoft, the SSIS is a cluster role in the cluster, so I assume they added SSIS as a cluster resource.

[image]

to instal SQL + SSIS in the second node, do I need to change any parameter for SSIS? or can I just install sql as a new cluster node + SSIS service normally? I know we save packages on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SSIS\ServiceConfigFile", so maybe just to be sure the new node has it's services pointed here too?

I'm asking because i'm reading this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-ssis-in-a-cluster?view=sql-server-ver16

and it mentions changing some values and parameters, and I got confused now because I remember in the past I did this, and didn't change much.

Thank you !